# Camera View Blank in Blender v3.3 and v3.4 but Renders Okay

Tags: camera

After I upgraded to Blender V3.3, I just get a dark screen when I hit NUMPAD 0. It does the animation of the camera moving toward the screen and the cube (or object) rotating, but then the 3d viewport goes black instead of showing the camera viewport rectangle. All menus are still visible. I reinstalled and went back to factory settings and removed all add-ons, but no joy.  It happens even when using the default cube scene. I have checked and compared settings with v3.2 (which has no issues), but I didn't find anything different. It is not an problem with the clipping settings. The problem persists with v3.4 as well.  Pressing NUMPAD 0 again returns back to the 3d view just fine, and it renders okay.  I'm just unable to view through the camera lens. Any ideas?